# Alinear en esquina imagen con texto centrado dentro de `<td></td>`

Tags: html, css

Buen día. Mi duda es: ¿Cómo coloco en una esquina de una celda `<td></td>` una imagen sin que afecte el centrado del taxto? de manera que logre lo que se muestra en la imagen siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado usando `position:absolue;top:0;left:100%;` pero la imagen se sale de la celda y me la coloca en la esquina de la página. De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día M.Gar, lo que yo ocupo en esos casos es un float. Por ejemplo:

```
<td style="position:relative"> <!-- Elemento padre -->
    <img src="algo.jpg" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:100%;"> <!--Elemento hijo -->
</td>
```

Podrías intentar con eso por favor.

Comment: De esta manera me posiciona la imagen a la derecha, pero no en la parte superior y el texto lo mueve un poco a la izquierda por lo cual ya no s emuestra centrado.

Comment: Tengo otra respuesta, podrías dejar tu imagen con position absolute, pero recuerda que es un objeto hijo entonces al objeto padre, en este caso el td, dale un position: relative. Intenta y me comentas, sino lo seguimos resolviendo

Comment: Gracias Eliseo, eso soluciono el problema. Puedes agregarlo a tu respuesta para seleccionarla como tal :D

Comment: Listo, ha quedado. Muchas gracias por intentar con las opciones, asunto solucionado.